# Android JetPack Compose Testing. How do I check if the Toast message appears?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I tried to do this but it doesn't work.

```
onNodeWithTag(TestTag.OPEN_DRAWER_BUTTON).performClick()
onNodeWithTag(TestTag.SYNCHRONIZE_BUTTON).performClick()
onNodeWithText(activity.getString(R.string.success_update)).assertExists()
```

I get it.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (Text + EditableText contains 'Exchange rates have been updated!' (ignoreCase: false))
```

Drawer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Toasts don't appear in the tree of views, so there isn't a way to detect its existence from Compose UI Tests.

However, the recommended way for showing small messages to the user is [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/snackbar), which is rendered inside the view hierarchy. Therefore it can be detected from Compose UI Tests.

From Android Docs:
"Note that Snackbars are preferred for brief messages while the app is in the foreground."
"If your app is in the foreground, consider using a snackbar instead of using a toast. Snackbars include user-actionable options, which can provide a better app experience."